# Error Log Transformation could not be executed

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-basis, sap-gateway

We have a transactional App of SAP Fiori Element and the app is working fine in the DEV environment.
but in Quality /n/iwfnd/error_log it is giving an error

```
..ERROR_INFO    The transformation /1IWST/AAGTVCXNHUPOVLGMOY6T37L could not be executed
```

I tried debugging code but no clue what is wrong here.

Can you please let me know what went wrong.

Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 1):

Transformations in the `/1IWST/` namespace are technical [ST transformations](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenabap_st.htm) for OData.

Go to that transformation in `STRANS` tcode and open it

[image]

in the comments at the top-side you can check the name of the OData service.

The errors in this transformation mean there is some inconsistency in your OData model.
Try to re-import the model and re-check the attribuites.